# Can you sell any of the new import/export special vehicles? Such as the ramp buggie

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought the ramp buggy thinking it would be amazing but after about 10 cars go over it it starts smoking. Is there any way to sell it? I looked it up and someone said that you can't own more than one because it will trade the first one in but now I have 2... HELP!

Comment: You can sell cars at Los Santos Customs, but I'm not sure they take special vehicles such as this. Take it there, and one of the options in the customization list is to sell the vehicle.

Comment: I've tried this. You can customize a lot of it but the 'sell' dosent pop up.

Answer (score 1):

How sad it is, there is no option for a Special Vehicle or any Warstock C&C vehicle to sell it.